# Mathematical approach for finding baseline shifts in data

Tags: r, signal-processing, boxplot, noise, quality-control

I have a raw signal from a sensor which is attached in this question . The x-axis is time, and the y-axis is the signal response. As you can see from the data, the baseline of the noisy signal shifts from approximately t1 = 22 s to a new baseline value at t2 = 24 s. I am using R to do the analysis. What I did was  group the data every 0.5s and plot the  box-plots for that group as shown in the figure. This approach is helpful, but changes slightly depending on time interval you define for the boxplots and also the noise in the signal. Is there any other  mathematical/ statistical way to figure out when exactly this baseline shift takes place and at what time the final baseline value is reached?. Since there are hundreds of such probes, I would like the program to automatically find t1 and t2 ,than the user looking at the graph manually. 
[image: Raw signal]

[image: Boxplots of data every 0.5 s]

Comment: Do you know the statistical properties of the noise? Do they have a mean of 0, for instance, and are they normally distributed (they actually look by eye to be negatively skewed, perhaps). Also, if you're looking at this in real time, a visual trick that can help is a running mean, or at least a running smoothed value from averaging together the k nearest entries.

Answer (score 1):

This is a huge field of research. It is referred to as statistical quality control. The literature on this field is massive.

The foundation of quality control methods is based on Shewhart charts. Then some benchmark methods have been developed specifically : EWMA charts (Exponentially weighted moving average chart) and CUSUM (cumulative charts ) charts. These two were later extended to handle multivariate data. Despite of this, the $T^2$ hotelling chart remains the main benchmark in multivariate control.

Looking at your data, CUSUM is a way to go. Also CUSUM will tell you exactly what time you lost control.

I would like to mention that also you can handle this problem using change point detection methods. Such methods are also mostly based on control charts, but have also been tackled through regression approaches.